# D3.js: drawing a colour gradient across an area?

Tags: d3.js

I would like to use D3 to draw a colour gradient with multiple stops - transitioning from red, to orange, to yellow, to green, to blue, to pink, to purple.

This is as far as I have got, from red to blue: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2zue/

I do this by drawing rectangles and interpoloating the colours:

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, values.length - 1])
  .range(["hsl(62,100%,90%)", "hsl(228,30%,20%)"]);
...
g.each(function(d) {
  color.interpolate(d.value);

  d3.select(this).selectAll("rect")
    .data(values)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", x)
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand)
    .style("fill", color);
});
```

I based this on Mike Bostock's HSL colour scale example: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3014589

However, now I wonder if I should be using an SVG linear gradient instead, like http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/4433087 or http://jsfiddle.net/ZCwrx/

What's the best way to do this - rectangles, or linear gradients?

Comment: Using SVG gradients is almost certainly going to give you better performance.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to submit this as an answer, even though it's not a very good question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SVG gradients is the preferred way of doing this. It's easier to code and will almost certainly give you better performance.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code for SVG gradient with stops and starts:

// define the gradient, as grad, set the vertical height of the start/stop via `y1` and `y2`

```
var grad = svg.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient")
    .attr({
      "id" : "grad",
      "x1" : "0%",
      "x2" : "0%",
      "y1" : "100%",
      "y2" : "65%"
    });

grad.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "50%")
  .style("stop-color", "yellow");

grad.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "70%")
  .style("stop-color", "skyblue");

mySvg.append("rect")
  .attr({ 
    width : width, 
    height : height, 
    fill : "url(#grad)" 
  })
```